# Which of these are sufficient conditions for a linear transformation to be an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra

Note: This is NOT a homework question.

I am preparing for a test and working through some old exam papers, but came across this following set of questions which I absolutely have NO idea how to reason out...

> Are the following linear transformations $T: V \to W$ isomorphisms? Motivate.
>
> 1. $\text{rank}(T)= \dim(V)$
> 2. $\text{rank}(T) = \dim(W)$
> 3. $R(T) = W = V$
> 4. $\text{nullity}(T) = 0 \text{ and } R(T)=W$

Even if you cannot provide me with the answers, can someone PLEASE provide me with the reasoning behind each (or some) of them that will help guide me to a better understanding as to how I can go about answering these questions.

Comment: What is denoted $R(T)$?

Comment: $\text{Range}(T)$

Comment: That is meaningless: the range can't be $V$ as proposd in 3.

Comment: @Bernard Can $T$ not map $V$ onto itself?

Comment: It can. The question could state this more precisely, but I think that is the correct interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should arm yourself with the [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), it will be immensely helpful. (also make sure you understand well the definitions of rank, nullity, and range, as well as what makes a linear map an isomorphism (injectivity and surjectivity))

1. Consider the dimension of $W$ as well. Could $\textrm{dim}(W)$ be less than $\textrm{rank}(T)$? Could it be greater than it? What would the implications be?
2. Same sort of considerations, what could the relative dimensions be, and what would comparing them to the rank tell you?
3. In this case, $T$ is obviously surjective, and the dimensions of $V$ and $W$ are equal. Use the rank-nullity theorem to conclude $T$ is injective.
4. This is a direct application of the definitions of nullity and range: in particular, $T$ is injective by the first statement, and surjective by the second.

Comment: Hence Conditions 1,3,4 would lead us to the isomorphism of the mapping only, am i right? and what does he mean by nullity, is it the kernal ?

Comment: @Mohamad: The nullity of $T$ is the dimension of the kernel of $T$.

Comment: ahaa thought so, about my opinion, am i right?

Comment: That is correct. In $2$, you can get a counterexample by choosing $V$ with dimension greater than that of $W$.